# Play with the structure of an XML File

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to user Ravis lib for data visualization and the structure of the XML file that Ravis uses is different that what we use in our company. These are as follows:

Ravis XML structure:

```
<Family>
<Node id="1" name="Father" desc="Head of the family" class="HOF"/>
<Node id="2" name="Mother" desc="Wife of Father" class="firstLady"/>
<Node id="3" name="Son" desc="Son" class="member"/>
<Node id="4" name="Daughter" desc="Daughter" class="member"/> 
<Node id="5" name="Daughter In Law" desc="Wife of Son" class="extendedMember"/>
<Node id="6" name="Grandson" desc="Child of Son" class="childMember"/>
<Edge fromID="1" toID="2" name="married" edgeClass="marriage"/>
<Edge fromID="1" toID="3" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
<Edge fromID="2" toID="3" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
<Edge fromID="1" toID="4" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
<Edge fromID="2" toID="4" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>  
<Edge fromID="3" toID="5" name="married" edgeClass="marriage"/>
<Edge fromID="3" toID="6" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
<Edge fromID="5" toID="6" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Family>
```

but the structure that we follow is

```
<Family>
<Node>
    <individual id="1" name="Father" desc="Head of the family" class="HOF"/>
</Node>
<Node>
    <individual id="2" name="Mother" desc="Wife of Father" class="firstLady"/>
</Node>
<Node>
    <individual id="3" name="Son" desc="Son" class="member"/>
</Node>
<Node>
    <individual id="4" name="Daughter" desc="Daughter" class="member"/>
</Node>
<Node>
    <individual id="5" name="Daughter In Law" desc="Wife of Son" class="extendedMember"/>
</Node>
<Node>
    <individual id="6" name="Grandson" desc="Child of Son" class="childMember"/>
</Node>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="1" toID="2" name="married" edgeClass="marriage"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="1" toID="3" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="2" toID="3" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="1" toID="4" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="2" toID="4" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="3" toID="5" name="married" edgeClass="marriage"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="3" toID="6" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
<Edge>
    <relation fromID="5" toID="6" name="gave birth to" edgeClass="birth"/>
</Edge>
 </Family>
```

Now I can't figure out how to display the data from our XML file on the graph. I am trying to do this using AS3 and FLex 4. The code is already there from Ravis community but it does not read the XML file in the format that I want it to reda.

Any help would be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could dynamically parse your XML using e4x syntax, couldn't you ?

```
        var to:XML = <Family/>;

        for each (var ind:XML in from..individual) {

            var indTo:XML = ind.copy();
            indTo.setName("Node");

            to.appendChild(indTo);
        }

        for each (var rel:XML in from..relation) {

            var relTo:XML = rel.copy();
            relTo.setName("Edge");

            to.appendChild(relTo);
        }
```

Comment: Thank You guys...I'll look into both these options and let you know what I used. Heartily thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is probably the "quick" way, given you can't just change your company structure. Can't tell where/how you'd slot it in from here though.